# How to load images in joomla component template

Tags: joomla

I am trying to using image tag to load image to a component template.
By

```
<img src="\images\subfolder\image.jpg" />
```

but the images don't show in the page.
I am wondering why.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
<img src="<?php echo JURI::root()?>images/subfolder/image.jpg" />
```

Hope its works..